# Spartacus SSR mode :After Applying AuthGuard on Component , login screen is displayed momentarily on refresh though user is already logged in

Tags: javascript, angular, server-side-rendering, spartacus-storefront

I am applying Spartacus **AuthGuard** for some component so that only logged in user can access them, if not then it will redirect Guest to the Login page. It is working fine without SSR mode but when I serve the application using SSR mode then on Refresh,  for the logged-in user it redirects to the Login page for a fraction of a second before redirecting to the requisite page.

This problem persists even on *Disable SSR*  mode for the component having AuthGuard.
If I remove the AuthGuard from the component then this problem does not happen.

AuthGuard Code :

```
  canActivate(): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
    return this.authService.isUserLoggedIn().pipe(
      map((isLoggedIn) => {
        if (!isLoggedIn) {
          this.authRedirectrvice.reportAuthGuard();
          return this.router.parseUrl(this.semanticPathService.get('login'));
        }
        return isLoggedIn;
      })
    );
  }
```

I believe it is happening due to server-side rendering as it is never redirected from the browser side(I  ensured it by debugging). So is there any solution to avoid redirection from the server-side for a logged user?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

### Edit 2023-02-13

Not to spend unnecessary time on full server-side-rendering of a `my-account/*` (and similar auth-protected pages), you can return an immediate CSR fallback (with shell `index.html`) for certain URLs. You need to configure `renderingStrategyResolver` in `server.ts`, like in the following example:

```js
// server.ts

const ALWAYS_CSR_PAGES: RegExp = /* your regex here */;

NgExpressEngineDecorator.get({
  renderingStrategyResolver: (req: express.Request) =>
    req.originalUrl.match(ALWAYS_CSR_PAGES)
      ? RenderingStrategy.ALWAYS_CSR
      : RenderingStrategy.DEFAULT,

  /*...*/
})
```

For more, see [docs](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_COMPOSABLE_STOREFRONT/eaef8c61b6d9477daf75bff9ac1b7eb4/c48860c28fbf443d906c682a2aed23b2.html?q=renderingStrategyResolver#renderingstrategyresolver).

### Original answer 2021-03-24

The UI flickering is unavoidable, becasue SSR doesn't know about the user context, by design. So in SSR you can't get the render of the logged in user. Only in CSR it's possible.

But here described the workaround, how to avoid displaying the Login Page UI for a fraction of time, but some custom, different UI instead:
https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/12537

Comment: Krysztof, is your answer still valid or Spartacus has provided another way around how to improve this behavior?

Comment: @ArtemZur thanks for pinging me. I edited the above answer, now with providing a more useful solution, I believe.

Comment: In our case the original answer is still better as we have *some* PDP's accessible only for authenticated users. So they see the blink when logged in, but obviously we need PDP being rendered, in general.

Comment: @MirosławGrochowski I guess for those special "private" products meant for only logged-in users, you render in SSR only some ghost design? And in the browser, depending whether an user actually is logged in you: (a) fetch the product data and show a proper PDP content OR (b) redirect to the login page?

Comment: @KrzysztofPlatis yes, for "private" products we render ghost. And in the browser it is either (a), OR (b) but, for (b), in our case, it is required to redirect to 404 page (this page has the "login" button, with the relevant message).